# Stack Smashing Detected at End of Program

Tags: c, arrays, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am currently testing a program on a smaller scale to distinguish a problem when I attempt to exit the program by `return 0;` at the end of the main function.

Main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Header.h"

int main (void)
{
        int i;
        int Fin = 0;


        Student sStu;
        Array aAry;
        Student *Stu = &sStu;
        Array *Ary = &aAry;

        InitArray(Ary, 1);

        while(Fin != 2)
        {
                printf("Please choose a selection.\n");
                printf("1. Add Student\n");
                printf("2. Print Students\n");
                printf("3. Exit\n");
                scanf("%d", &i);
                switch(i)
                {
                        case 1:
                        {
                                AddStudent(Stu, Ary);
                                break;
                        }
                        case 2:
                        {
                                for(i = 0; i < Ary->Size; i++)
                                {
                                        printf("%s %d\n", Stu[i].Name, Stu[i].IDn);
                                }
                                break;
                        }
                        case 3:
                        {
                                return 0;
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

Header.h

```
#ifndef HEADER_H_
#define HEADER_H_

typedef struct student
{
        char Name[30];
        int IDn;
}Student;

typedef struct array
{
        Student *Student;
        size_t Used;
        size_t Size;
}Array;


void InitArray(Array *Ary, int InitSize);
void AddArray(Array *Ary);
Student AddStudent(Student *Stu, Array *Ary);

#endif
```

Grade.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "Header.h"

void InitArray(Array *Ary, int InitSize)
{
        Ary->Student =  malloc(InitSize * sizeof(Student));
        Ary->Used = 0;
        Ary->Size = InitSize;
        memset(&Ary->Student[0], 0 , sizeof(Student) * InitSize);
}

void AddArray(Array *Ary)
{
        Student Stud;
        if(Ary->Used == Ary->Size)
        {
                Ary->Size *= 2;
                Ary->Student = realloc(Ary->Student, Ary->Size * sizeof(Student));
        }

        strcpy(Ary->Student[Ary->Used].Name, Stud.Name);
        Ary->Student[Ary->Used].IDn = Stud.IDn;

        Ary->Used++;
}

Student AddStudent(Student *Stu, Array *Ary)
{
        int i;

        printf("\nStudent ID numbers cannot be the same!\n");
        printf("Please enter the student's name: ");
        scanf("%s", Stu[Ary->Used].Name);
        printf("Please enter the student's ID Number: ");
        scanf("%d", &Stu[Ary->Used].IDn);
        AddArray(Ary);
        printf("\n");
        return;
}
```

At the end of the file, when I try to `return 0;` I get this error:

> *** stack smashing detected ***: ./a.out terminated
>   Segmentation fault (core dumped)

When I use valgrind, I get this output:

```
==9966== Invalid write of size 1
==9966==    at 0x402C6C3: strcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==9966==    by 0x8048687: AddArray (in /home/ctj0033/CSCE_1040/Homework/2_Homework/2_Test/a.out)
==9966==    by 0x804874B: AddStudent (in /home/ctj0033/CSCE_1040/Homework/2_Homework/2_Test/a.out)
==9966==    by 0x804881C: main (in /home/ctj0033/CSCE_1040/Homework/2_Homework/2_Test/a.out)
==9966==  Address 0x41f804c is 0 bytes after a block of size 36 alloc'd
```

valgrind terminates due to an fatal error during my attempt to exit my program.

It only happens at the end and I can print the contents of the struct array properly. I have looked into `realloc();` since I am fairly sure the error lies within that, however I am uncertain precisely what I have done wrong. I have attempted to alter the way I allocate the memory in `InitArray();` and the way I use `realloc();` but to no avail.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Valgrind says the segfault happens at the `strcpy` in `AddArray`. Compile with `-g` to have it show line numbers.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I am going to go try that.

Comment: I would imagine it is because that is the way I was taught to do it by any teacher or instructor I have had in the past. It is clearer to read in my opinion I suppose.

Comment: `scanf("%s", Stu[Ary->Used].Name);`. Looks like you are passing in a single (stack allocated) `Student` into `Addstudent` but then using it as an array of `Student`s.

Comment: @Alan Au If I understand you correctly, what I need to fix is pass multiple (Stack allocated) `Student` into the function rather than the single I am doing currently?

Comment: @nerdistcolony it's definitely not the worst formatting I've ever seen. While not my personal favorite, it's fine as long as it's consistent. The only thing wrong are the braces for the `case`s: they are unnecessary and misleading because they don't prevent fall-through.

Comment: @Arrowkill Not if I read your code correctly. AFAICS `Stu` is really a temporary variable used to store input from the user. Which is then copied into the array by `AddArray`. That being the case, I think you should not pass `Stu` into `AddStudent` at all. Just declare it as a local variable inside `AddStudent`. Your actual list of students is dynamically allocated and stored inside `array`.

Comment: @Kninnug I had an error a week or so ago with my `case`s that was resolved by adding scope blocks or `{}` to them. I just do it now to prevent the possibility of an error.

Comment: @Kinnug  Consistency is orthogonal to value. He could consistently put 10 semicolons at the end of every statement. That wouldn't make it good. It wouldn't be the worst thing someone could do to code, but that still isn't a good reason to do it.

Comment: @Alan Au I declared it as a local variable instead and it changed nothing. In relation to my error.

Comment: @Arrowkill - that is really an absurd prophylactic. Just try to understand when and why you might add { } to a case statement. I've done it once or twice, once in professional code, but typically you don't need it, and it is a waste of space and more clutter. More clutter is not good. I've worked in kernel groups and professionally for 30 years, and none of the C code repositories I've seen have your very cluttered spaced out style of coding, thank god, or I'd go nuts. People who are good just want concise but not cramped code and just read code on the fly and don't need the sugarcoated syntax

Comment: @Arrowkill Please show your updated code (as an edit - keep the original). For example, are you still accessing it as an array?

Comment: @nerdistcolony You have a point, I will not deny that. However my goal here is not to prove or disprove differences in practice, regardless of the length of experience by comparison. The point of this is to resolve an error. Your advice, or opinion depending on the person, has been heard. We have digressed from the purpose of this question and should avoid digressing further.

Comment: @Arrowkill - To wit, my point, if any, is, that I was so put off by the overkill spacing and scrolling that I ran screaming from the question. Otherwise I would have studied it. -- also I wasn't trying to pull rank so much as to say - I've seen a lot of code, but not much of that style, except by noobs here and eccentric Java coders

Comment: Your call to `strcpy` in `AddArray()` is using `Stud.Name` uninitialised. I believe you meant to use the passed in parameter `Stu` instead. `Student Stud` isn't required at all.

Comment: Okay, I will try that.

Comment: @nerdistcolony That makes more sense, In future, I will modify it so that others have an easier time reading it. Personal choice vs Public opinion are very different as I was just reminded xD

Comment: Actually, the posted code doesn't compile. `AddArray()` takes two parameters and you're only passing one.

Comment: @DaV My apologies, when I editted my code I neglected to modify that

Comment: `Fin` in `main()` is uninitialized when its value is used. Undefined behavior.

Comment: I did alter that to defining it as 0. It however did nothing for the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your immediate problem is that you're trying to use an "invalid pointer". (Actually, it's a completely valid pointer, it just points to a wrong place)

`sStu` is a `Student`, and `Stu` is a pointer to it. But when you add your second student, you write to `Stu[1]` - which is the space after `sStu`. Most likely there's something else in this space, so when you write to `Stu[1]`, you overwrite something else. (It's unpredictable exactly *what* will be in that space.)

It looks like you want to use `Ary->Student` everywhere you have `Stu`.

(If you do that, you might find some more problems - such as the fact that you check if you need to expand the array *after* writing to the next element)

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem in my question, and as you predicted, caused a few more. Thanks though!

Comment: @Arrowkill Not "caused", but maybe "exposed".

Comment: You are right in that sense, however despite my poor choice of wording, that was what I meant.