# Program works but get **stack smashing detected** in the end

Tags: c

I already check this discussion: [Stack Smashing Detected at End of Program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32959038/stack-smashing-detected-at-end-of-program)

But it's not the same problem.

In my case. My program works, but if I run 10x: 6x no error, and 4x give me "stack smashing detected" at the end, with a wrong output with the error. I found a lot of people saying that it is caused by gcc or linux SO. In compilers online I run more than 20x and never had this error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void bubbleSort(int v[], int tam)
{
    int aux=0, i=0, j=0;
    for (i = 0; i < tam; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",i );
        for (j = 0; j < tam - i; j++)
        {
            if (v[j] > v[j + 1])
            {
                printf("a\n");
                aux = v[j];
                printf("b\n");
                v[j] = v[j + 1];
                printf("c\n");
                v[j + 1] = aux;
                printf("d\n");
        }
    }
}
}

int main(void)
{
    int v[10] = {1, 5, 6, 8, 9, 0, 4, 3, 2, 7};
    int n = 10;
    bubbleSort(v, n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d,", v[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

My output:

```
0
a
b
c
d
a
b
c
d
a
b
c
d
a
b
c
d
a
b
c
d
a
b
c
d
1
a
b
c
d
a
b
c
d
a
b
c
d
a
b
c
d
a
b
c
d
a
b
c
d
2
a
b
c
d
a
b
c
d
a
b
c
d
a
b
c
d
a
b
c
d
3
a
b
c
d
a
b
c
d
a
b
c
d
a
b
c
d
a
b
c
d
4
a
b
c
d
a
b
c
d
a
b
c
d
a
b
c
d
5
a
b
c
d
a
b
c
d
6
a
b
c
d
7
a
b
c
d
8
a
b
c
d
9
a
b
c
d


-1228779264,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,
*** stack smashing detected ***
```

---

Valgrind LOG:

```
==7890== 
==7890== Process terminating with default action of signal 6 (SIGABRT)
==7890==    at 0x4E6F428: raise (raise.c:54)
==7890==    by 0x4E71029: abort (abort.c:89)
==7890==    by 0x4EB17E9: __libc_message (libc_fatal.c:175)
==7890==    by 0x4F5315B: __fortify_fail (fortify_fail.c:37)
==7890==    by 0x4F530FF: __stack_chk_fail (stack_chk_fail.c:28)
==7890==    by 0x4006EC: main ()
==7890== 
==7890== HEAP SUMMARY:
==7890==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7890==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 1,024 bytes allocated
==7890== 
==7890== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==7890== 
==7890== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==7890== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Abortado
```

---

->LINUX:
Ubuntu 16.04

->GCC:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-5/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-5 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9)
```

Comment: It should be `for (j = 0; j < tam - i - 1; j++)` otherwise you might access the array out of bounds which seems to be the case.

Comment: When `i` is 0, `j` will run from 0 to 9, and `j+1` will be 10, so you're accessing the array beyond it bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `bubbleSort`, when `i` is 0, `for (j = 0; j < tam - i; j++)` is `for (j = 0; j < tam - 0; j++)`, so `j` iterates up to and including `tam-1`.

Then, in the loop, you compare `v[j]` with `v[j + 1]`. The latter may be `v[tam-1 + 1]`, which is `v[tam]`, which is outside the array. That alone is a reference not permitted by the C standard. And then the code goes on to swap `v[j]` with `v[j + 1]`, if the comparison evaluated to true. That writes data outside the bounds of the array `v`, so it corrupts some memory in your process.

Comment: You're correct, that was the problem. But strange, because times worked and in others presented error, and in the online compiler there is no error, always works as expected. Thanks a lot.